# PHP - Unable to send JSON correctly

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm not sure why this isn't working, as a lot of the examples on the internet suggest doing it this way. Anyway, I have a SQL result that I've converted to JSON and now I'm trying to use that with Javascript.

```
json_encode($test, true); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var obj = (<?php echo $test; ?>);
alert(obj.toSource());
</script>
```

This does not work and Chrome gives me an error of "illegal character" and the Javascript variable somehow displays some x-debug HTML from the PHP server:
[image]

If I simple echo the JSON out to display on the webpage that works fine without any errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $test is not the encoded json

Comment: Are you sure you're assigning `$test` the JSON encoded value? Also what are the brackets for?

Comment: looks like html to me, not JSON

Comment: it's some sort of stack trace for maybe like undefined variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$test = json_encode($test, true);
```

`json_encode` doesn't change the variable in place.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a couple of things wrong here..

```
json_encode($test, true);
```

I think you're probably thinking of [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), but the second parameter to [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is supposed to be a bitmask of options.  Passing `true` here is probably wrong.

@ElmoVanKielmo is also correct, the variable doesn't change because you call a function, you must reassign the variable to the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You got hmtl that looks line an xdebug error/notice message. Fix that before you proceed! (You cut out the part where the message is put).

Additionally you do not encode $test correctly. json_encode returns the changed value and does not modify it by reference.